# Initialize a vector with a custom allocator

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I'm trying to initialize a vector with an explicit allocator, but the code below seems not working:

```
vector<int> a1(allocator<int>());
cout << a1.size();  //Error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
```

There is also a working version:

```
vector<int> a2(*(new allocator<int>()));
cout << a2.size();  // OK
```

And another:

```
vector<int> a3(a2, allocator<int>());
cout << a3,size();  // OK
```

I want to know why only the first version is not working. I'm using MSVC with C++17, and it seems the compiler won't regard `a1` as an object. Thanks.

Comment: `a1` is a function declaration. You fell victim to the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks a lot! I'm new to this terminology actually. I will check to figure out how it works.

Comment: have you tried vector<int> a1( allocator<int>{ } ); ?

Comment: google "most vexing parse".

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Thanks, this one works!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who gives me suggestions, this is known as "most vexing parse" and can be fixed by uniform initialization as:

```
vector<int> a1(allocator<int>{});
```

So that a1 is now a vector. Otherwise, a1 will be interpreted as a function, that receives a parameter of type `std::allocator<int> (*)()` and returns `vector<int>`.